# Shnayim Vachamishim Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred fifty-two?

### שנים וחמישים ושלוש מאות - מי יודע?‏

The traditional Passover song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea) implies a possible presupposition that there is a Jewish significance to be found for each [natural number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number). Accordingly, there is an [ongoing series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) on Mi Yodeya that is attempting to unearth significant Judaism facts about each number, in sequence.

What significant Judaism facts are there about the number 352? The more significant within Judaism and the more intrinsically dependent on the value 352, the stronger the answer. Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Let us not revert to lazy gematria answers.

Comment: Isaac I think it's fair for you to post the obvious answer to 353 354 355 yourself with the question to avoid any FGITW problems and because stack exchange is fairly adamant that asking and answering your own question is perfectly fine. People can still post other interesting answers

Answer (score 6):

352 days in the shortest allowed calendar year

Source: Mishna Arakhin 2:2 says that the court would never allow fewer than 4 months to have a 30th day